# Hacker evidence from "netstat -a"

Tags: windows, netstat

What *exactly* do you look for in "netstat -a" results that would indicate an unknown user on your network, please?

---

Thank you for the replies below.  I edited this original question (above) earlier, but apparently in the wrong interface. I apologize for that.

To clarify the question, as you write, netstat is not intended as a hacker's diagnostic tool: I am sorry that I apparently left you with this impression. The question intended to ask whether there were any elements within the result-set of running netstat  that a "Super User" would interpret as clearly suspicious, e.g (... I suppose), an IP address which is not your own, or a an address that is known to originate in a suspicious place, or some string known to indicate a problem, etc.

If the answer is no, then that fine...

Thank you again for reading my question.

Comment: Netstat alone can't detect attacks. Without context, there is not really a reliable way of determining whether a connection is indicative of bad things.

Comment: I've edited my question to answer your edit, but long story short, the answer is yes and no ... it can give _some_ information, but it doesn't paint the entire picture

Answer (score 1):

The [`netstat`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490947.aspx) command is used to give information about active connections and ports that your computer is listening on (along with some ethernet statistics). It won't tell you if you someone has "hacked" your computer, though it *might* tell you if someone is remotely connected to your computer (assuming they haven't compromised your computer to hide that kind of information).

`netstat` also won't tell you if anyone else is on your network, it can only tell you what your local computer is connected to. If you're concerned with someone unauthorized on your network, you could use a tool like [`nmap`](https://nmap.org/) or [`wireshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/) and do some basic probing to see if there are any devices on your network that you don't recognize. If you have a WiFi network, your wireless AP should have a log of some sort that can tell you if a device is on your wireless that you don't recognize.

If your computer is acting unusual and you really do suspect someone has compromised it, it would be a good idea to disconnect it from the internet all together, backup any sensitive data, and try a fresh install.

To answer your edit directly:

> The question intended to ask whether there were any elements within the result-set of running netstat that a "Super User" would interpret as clearly suspicious, e.g (... I suppose), an IP address which is not your own, or a an address that is known to originate in a suspicious place, or some string known to indicate a problem, etc.

Again, using `netstat` will only show you what your computer is connected to; as an example, this is the result when I run `netstat -a`:

```
C:\>netstat -a

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1032         localhost:1033        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1033         localhost:1032        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6118         localhost:6119        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6119         localhost:6118        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.5:1031       fileserver:microsoft-ds  ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.5:6316       imap11:imaps           CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.5:7345       stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.5:7356       stackoverflow:https    ESTABLISHED
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1900           *:*
```

From these results alone I can see that my IP (`192.168.1.5`) has connected to my NAS (`fileserver`), an email server (`imap11`) and the StackOverflow web site (`stackoverflow:https`).

I can also see that my local host IP (`127.0.0.1`) has some connections established and my machine is also listening on `UDP` port 1900 (`UDP 0.0.0.0:1900 *:*`). These might concern me if the only tool I had was `netstat`, but I can also use the [Windows Resource Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Monitor) (or [`TCPView`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx)) to see which programs have active connections. I could also shutdown programs one by one and see which connections leave the `ESTABLISHED` state, but that could take a while...

Looking at those results, I can see that the `localhost` connections are my Firefox instance (which some program use `localhost` for inter-process communications), so I don't need to concern myself with that connection and the UDP is actually my media playing program that has an interactive interface (for remote play, etc.) and UDP doesn't go outside (or into) my network and I have an active firewall blocking it, so I don't need to concern my self with that either.

**IFF** I happened to see a connection I could not correlate to a known active connection (i.e. my email or internet), then I would break out the other tools I mentioned to further investigate that specific connection.

Keep in mind that `netstat` will only show you active `TCP` or `UDP` connections, and while TCP and UDP are the most common protocols, there are a slew of others that exist that are potential attack avenues that `netstat` cannot show. Additionally, an attacker or malicious program could bypass all protocols and use there own custom connection protocol using RAW sockets (low level programming). Granted some methods would require certain levels of administrative privilege, while others wouldn't.

So `netstat` can tell you *some* information, but it doesn't paint the whole picture and it especially can't give enough information to validate that something malicious is actually happening.

Hope that can help.